# Nesting an If Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, nested

How would you convert the following into a **nested** if statement?

```
if (numProductivity > 69 && numProductivity <= 199) bonus = BONUS_3;
if (numProductivity > 30 && numProductivity <= 69) bonus = BONUS_2;
if (numProductivity > 0 && numProductivity <= 30) bonus = BONUS_1;
else bonus = BONUS_4;
```

Comment: @RealSkeptic It's valid, but almost certainly not correct (I assume there should be `else`s before two of the `if`s). I wonder why OP wants to nest it too.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You are right, but actually the conditions are mutually exclusive, so you don't need an else, it's just that the last `else` is incorrect, because it will override the results of the first two ifs. I guess adding `else` is actually a form of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a nested if statement is appropriate. Rather a chain of if-else statements expresses the idea better.

```
   if (numProductivity <= 0)
       bonus = 0;  // I GUESSED AT THIS
   else if (numProductivity <= 30) 
       bonus = BONUS_1;
   else if (numProductivity <= 69)
       bonus = BONUS_2;
   else if (numProductivity <= 199) 
       bonus = BONUS_3;
   else // >= 200
       bonus = BONUS_4;
```

I assume that 0 productivity is possible and it should be awarded no bonus rather than the highest possible bonus.

I assume that BONUS_4 is the highest bonus (based on the naming of the other cases) -- your original code is unclear on that matter, since it will (incorrectly) assign BONUS_4 for any numProductivity > 30.

If we really want nested ifs:

```
   if (numProductivity > 0) {
      if (numProductivity > 30) {
          if (numProductivity > 69) {
              if (numProductivity > 199) {
                  bonus = BONUS_4;
              }
              else { // <= 199
                  bonus = BONUS_3;
              }
          } 
          else { // <= 69
              bonus = BONUS_2;
          }
      }
      else { // <= 30
          bonus = BONUS_1;
      }
   }
   else { // <= 0
       bonus = 0;
   }
```

but look how much harder that is to read.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear ***why*** you want to turn your posted code into a nested `if`, nor is it clear that your posted code is correct (for example, I assume that BONUS_2 and BONUS_3 were meant to be valid, as posted your code will only have visible BONUS_1 and BONUS_4 results). To nest it, first test that the results are in your expected range; then test subranges. Like

```
if (numProductivity > 0 && numProductivity < 200) {
    if (numProductivity <= 30) {
        bonus = BONUS_1;
    } else if (numProductivity <= 69) {
        bonus = BONUS_2;
    } else {
        bonus = BONUS_3;
    }
} else {
    bonus = BONUS_4;
}
```

Comment: Your solution seems to follow the intent of the OP in that low productivity (<= 0) and high productivity (>= 200) get the same bonus, but surely that can't be what's really wanted?

Comment: @another-dave It's possible that BONUS_4 is zero. Testing the range with one `if` and then subranges internally is the only reasonable way I could see to nest the logic, but I agree that OP's posted logic **must** be incomplete.

Comment: True; and on reflection I am merely assuming that higher productivity leads to a higher bonus :-)

Answer (score -1):

It's no have possibility to nesting...
Nesting example:

```
 if( x == 30 ) {
         if( y == 10 ) {
            System.out.print("X = 30 and Y = 10");
         }
      }
```

Comment: A little clarification, this was for a grade. Amazingly my professor did not catch that only Bonus_1 and Bonus_2 were possible. Then only problem is that I needed to submit the code with a nested version of my if statements. Thanks for pointing that out. I knew I had the issue once, but I thought I had resolved it.

Oh, and @another-dave, apparently a 0 production amount still gets $50, but how nice would it be to get a $200 bonus for doing absolutely nothing. Thank you all so much for the help.